# SEO changing main domain in Google Search results?

Tags: seo, htaccess, redirects, 301-redirect

At the moment there is 3 domains pointing to same server for content, and of course their have the `canonical` URL set to tell Google about the duplicate content, but the questions is, if we take into consideration the follow:

- url_1 - `something.se`
- url_2 - `somethingelse.com`
- url_3 - `something-notcool.com`

Right now if I Google something something for example it will go to `something.se`, but I want to tell Google to use `somethingelse.com` instead.

So, how can I do that? I tried with 301 redirects, but it end up in infinity loop when the person loaded `somethingelse.com`...

Comment: If you've allowed all three domains to be indexed in Google, then that's what will happen. Not really sure what you're trying to achieve - do you just want the one domain indexed in Google from those three?

Comment: yes, I just one domain to indexed, and remove the other 2, but the client still wants to be able to see them if he typed the address..

Comment: Okay, added the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just `NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW` [[link]](http://www.robotstxt.org/meta.html) the two that you don't want indexed in Google then. Register all three in Google Webmaster Tools and for the two that you wish to be removed from Google's index, just remove the entire site in the 'Remove URL' [[link]](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/164734?hl=en) section.